# Keyword not supported: 'port' error in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, port, ado

I'm trying to create an API server, and I need to have access to MySQL database. I have this piece of code:

```
public static class Database
{
        private const string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=contoso_inc;Uid=root;Pwd=f6e527xp;";

        public static IEnumerable<User> Execute(string query)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                connection.Open();
                
                var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                var result = new List<User>();
                
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var user = new User
                    {
                        year = (uint) reader.GetValue(0),
                        month = (string) reader.GetValue(1),
                        users_num = (uint) reader.GetValue(2)
                    };
                    
                    result.Add(user);

                }
                
                reader.Close();

                return result;
            }
        }
}
```

The error appears on this line: `connection.Open();`. So apparently I can't use Port for some reason. What is the problem?

P.S. I've seen related questions, but most of them belong to the Entity Framework topic. I don't have `DbContext` here, so it didn't help.

Comment: The [documentation for MySQL connection strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-string.html) indicates using `host:port`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using the wrong driver for connect.
try install this nuget package

```
Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.26
```

then, you can do something like this:

```
public static class Database
{
    private const string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=contoso_inc;Uid=root;Pwd=f6e527xp;";

    public static IEnumerable<User> Execute(string query)
    {
        using (var connection = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
            connection.Open();
            
            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var result = new List<User>();
            
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var user = new User
                {
                    year = (uint) reader.GetValue(0),
                    month = (string) reader.GetValue(1),
                    users_num = (uint) reader.GetValue(2)
                };
                
                result.Add(user);

            }
            
            reader.Close();

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for [`SqlConnection.ConnectionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring), I don't see any sign of a key for "port". If you need to specify the port, you can do so in the `Server` part:

> The name or network address of the instance of SQL Server to which to connect. The port number can be specified after the server name:
>
> `server=tcp:servername, portnumber`

So perhaps you want: "Server=localhost,3306;..." or "Server=tcp:localhost,3306;..." - if you actually think you need to really need to specify the port at all.

Comment: That is the correct syntax for using `SqlConnection`, but the OP said they want to connect to MySQL, so they're using the wrong ADO.NET library.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger: Gosh, I hadn't even seen that - I wonder whether it was added within the 5 minutes grace period (hence the lack of edit) or whether I just didn't spot it.

Answer (score 0):

The port is specified in the Server keyword, in your example use:

```
"Server=localhost, 3306;Database=contoso_inc;Uid=root;Pwd=f6e527xp;"
```

connection string is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

Comment: That is the correct syntax for using `SqlConnection`, but the OP said they want to connect to MySQL; they need to switch to a MySQL ADO.NET library.